# MySQL referencing, to avoid repeating myself?

Tags: mysql

I have this snippet:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN
        AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tDone)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tIPN))/3600 >= 10
    THEN
        ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tDone)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tIPN))/3600,0)
    ELSE
        ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tDone)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tIPN))/3600,1)
    END 
FROM
    ...
```

Can I do anything to remove the duplication from this?  Something along these lines, for instance:  (Hypothetical code follows):

```
SET var = AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tDone)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tIPN))/3600
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN
        var > 10
    THEN
        ROUND(var,0)
    ELSE
        ROUND(var,1)
    END 
FROM
    ...
```

Comment: You can create a function, but functions are evil.

Comment: Evil why..?  Or was that sarcasm?

Comment: Functions are often tightly entangled with your database engine. If you want to change database later, it can become a hell. Also, some engines are less efficient at optimizing queries if they use functions. So, if you can avoid them, do it.

Comment: Not sarcasm then.  Got it!

Answer (score 2):

With a subquery you can do something like this :

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN avgtiPN >= 10 THEN ROUND(avgtiPN,0) ELSE ROUND(avgtiPN,1) END 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tDone)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tIPN))/3600 AS avgtiPN
   FROM
    ...) AS AVGQuery
```

But I am still uncertain if it is more readable.

Comment: And in general it's best to avoid subqueries when possible isn't it, especially as the base query grows in complexity?

Comment: Well I guess using a subquery to pre-calculate some values would be okay.

Comment: From a performance point of view, but it does nothing to enhance readability or maintainability of the code imho.

Comment: It enhance maintainablity because you only have to edit the `AVG` calculation once if needed.  Also if you have other values to pre-calculate in your aggregate then it might end up being more readable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but variable processing order is undefined for user-defined variables.  [This reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) in the MySQL documentation explains when this works and when it doesnt.